# Redux store does not have a valid reducer (combineReducer error)

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

First of all
The directory structure is as follows

```
├─redux
│  │  store.js
│  │
│  └─slices
│          userSlice.js
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userSlice from "./slices/userSlice";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  userSlice,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export default store;
```

userSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  loginState: false,
  accessToken: "",
  userId: "",
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userReducer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLogin: (state, action) => {
      state.loginState = true;
      state.accessToken = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setLogin } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice;
```

Each code is as follows

I need a few more reducers, so I used a combineReducer
and, I connected the reducer through configureStore, but the following error continues to occur

***Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.***

I don't know which one is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure the error comes from here, but you named your reducer `userReducer` in `createSlice` and `userSlice` in `combineReducers`.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not related to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are passing a `slice` to the `combineReducers(...)`. And `slice` !== `reducer`.

In your `userSlice.js`, you may want to change the last line to:

```js
// export default userSlice;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

You can take a look at the docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice

> The generated reducer function is suitable for passing to the Redux combineReducers function as a "slice reducer".

Comment: Oh.. I appriciate